# How do I get and install an unmodified kernel?

Tags: drivers, kernel

So, I want to learn how to develop drivers for Linux.

And for that I heard it's recommended to use an unmodified kernel, since distributions can patch/change it a lot.

I downloaded Ubuntu 10.04 (lucid): http://releases.ubuntu.com/lucid/ubuntu-10.04.1-desktop-i386.iso.torrent

I found this page: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/MainlineBuilds

**How do I know what's the most compatible kernel version for that Ubuntu release ?**

I could not understand from the wiki page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you click through [to see what's available](http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/?C=M;O=D), you'll see that many of the kernels end in the release name (that is `-maverick`, `-lucid` etc).

The *most* compatible ones will be the ones for the release you're using. In your case, 10.04 is Lucid.

But it is usually possible to mismatch versions pretty heavily. I used a `-maverick` kernel on Lucid for quite a while and then switched back to compiling them straight from kernel.org myself (as I still do).

Answer (score -1):

all your need is compile a kernel from source [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Kernel/Compile) you have all information you need for this purpose, how to get as oli say, what package do you need, how to install, etc..